# System of linear equations with constants appended

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you solve for $x$ and $y$, when there is a constant tagged on? $u, w, a, b, c, d$ are known.

$$
\begin{cases}
u = a x + b y + 1,\\
w = c x + d y + 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: c,d as well? ${}$

Comment: If $u$ and $w$ are known, then they’re also constants. Move all of the constant terms to one side and solve as usual.

Comment: First, solve for x on the first equation and you get x=(by+1-u)/(-a). Next, solver for y on the second equation, using the newly organized equation solving for x in place of the x. Here you get y=(-aw+a+cu-c)/(bc-ad). Then simply plug in your constants and you've solved for y. Use that new y value to go back and solve the first equation for x.

Answer (score 2):

Why not the usual
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}u-1 \\ w-1\end{pmatrix}
$$